# hibernate locked table

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, transactions

Why is this giving me a lock timeout:

```
for(int i = 0; i < playersCount ; i++) {
            StatUser stats = (StatUser) selectedUsers.get(i).getStatUsers().iterator().next();
            int gc = stats.getGamesPlayed();
            int gm = stats.getMakeCount();

            Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
            Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
            if(i == winnerIndex) {
                   stats.setGamesPlayed(gc++);
                   stats.setMakeCount(gm++);
                   session.update(stats);
                   session.flush();
                   tx.commit();
                   customTextBean.sendMail(selectedUsers.get(i).getEmail(), "Tillykke du har vundet");
            }
            else {
                stats.setGamesPlayed(gc++);
                session.update(stats);
                session.flush();
                tx.commit();
                customTextBean.sendMail(selectedUsers.get(i).getEmail(), "Tillykke " + winnersName + " skal lave kaffe");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Dont mind the weird way i find the user :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create a new transaction (`session.beginTransaction();`), then a new DB connection is created. So you have a transaction which has a read-lock on `stats` (from the `for` loop) and inside of that you try to write to the same row -> Deadlock.

To fix that, you first fetch all `StatUser`s with a second loop, close the first transaction and then iterate over the result in the code above. If you can't do that because you run out of memory, then Hibernate is no longer your friend and you must use custom SQL.

Other solutions: Use optimistic locking or read the data to be changed with custom SQL and instantiate the objects in the loop.